# Manually call Spring Annotation Validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

I'm doing a lot of our validation with Hibernate and Spring Annotations like so:

```
public class Account {
    @NotEmpty(groups = {Step1.class, Step2.class})
    private String name;

    @NotNull(groups = {Step2.class})
    private Long accountNumber;

    public interface Step1{}
    public interface Step2{}
}
```

And then in the controller it's called in the arguments:

```
public String saveAccount(@ModelAttribute @Validated({Account.Step1.class}) Account account, BindingResult result) {
   //some more code and stuff here
   return "";
}
```

But I would like to decide the group used based on some logic in the controller method. Is there a way to call validation manually? Something like `result = account.validate(Account.Step1.class)`?

I am aware of creating your own Validator class, but that's something I want to avoid, I would prefer to just use the annotations on the class variables themselves.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Spring provides [LocalValidatorFactoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/LocalValidatorFactoryBean.html), which implements the Spring [`SmartValidator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/SmartValidator.html) interface as well as the Java Bean Validation [`Validator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Validator.html) interface.

```java
// org.springframework.validation.SmartValidator - implemented by LocalValidatorFactoryBean
@Autowired
SmartValidator validator;

public String saveAccount(@ModelAttribute Account account, BindingResult result) {
    // ... custom logic
    validator.validate(account, result, Account.Step1.class);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        // ... on binding or validation errors
    } else {
        // ... on no errors
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the `BindingResult` value?

Comment: That is injected by Spring MVC. Well... I assumed in my answer that we are talking about MVC handler method, because `ModelAttribute` does not make sense in any other context.

Comment: It's a [`ValidatorFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ValidatorFactory.html) bean, not a validator [`FactoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.8/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html).  `FactoryBean` is a Spring thing, `ValidatorFactory` is a Java EE bean validation thing.

Comment: @M.Justin You are correct, I have deleted my old rant from the answer.

Answer (score 49):

Here is a code sample from [JSR 303 spec](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/)

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

Driver driver = new Driver();
driver.setAge(16);
Car porsche = new Car();
driver.setCar(porsche);


Set<ConstraintViolation<Driver>> violations = validator.validate( driver );
```

So yes, you can just get a validator instance from the validator factory and run the validation yourself, then check to see if there are violations or not.  You can see in the [javadoc for Validator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/Validator.html#validate%28T,%20java.lang.Class...%29) that it will also accept an array of groups to validate against.

Obviously this uses JSR-303 validation directly instead of going through Spring validation, but I believe spring validation annotations will use JSR-303 if it's found in the classpath

Comment: The thing is, that if you are using Spring MVC, you probably want `BindingResult` / `Errors` instead of `ConstraintViolation`s. So while your answer is correct, it is not a good fit for the question.

Comment: This might be useful for Spring Rest Controller. You can throw `new ConstraintViolationException(violations);` when `violations` is not empty. It will be exactly the same what Spring `@Validated` would have caused and can be handled by `@ControllerAdvice`.

Comment: I am a newbie, but this did not seem to work.  It gives a HV000183 exception, unable to initialize 'javax.el.ExpressionFactory'.

Answer (score 21):

If you have everything correctly configured, you can do this:

```
import javax.validation.Validator;

@Autowired
Validator validator;
```

Then you can use it to validate you object:

```
var errors = validator.validate(obj);
```

Comment: When has not errors return `null` or empty set?

Answer (score 11):

This link gives pretty good examples of using validations in Spring apps. 
https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/

I have found an example to run the validation programmitically in this article.

```
class MyValidatingService {

  void validatePerson(Person person) {
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Person>> violations = validator.validate(person);
    if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
      throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
    }
  } 
}
```

It throws `500` status, so it is recommended to handle it with custom exception handler.

```
@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
public class CustomGlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<CustomErrorResponse> constraintViolationException(HttpServletResponse response, Exception ex) throws IOException {
        CustomErrorResponse errorResponse = new CustomErrorResponse();
        errorResponse.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        errorResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
        errorResponse.setError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.getReasonPhrase());
        errorResponse.setMessage(ex.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorResponse, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Second example is from https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-error-handling-example/

Update:
Using validation is persistence layer is not recommended:
https://twitter.com/odrotbohm/status/1055015506326052865

Answer (score 7):

Adding to answered by @digitaljoel, you can throw the ConstraintViolationException once you got the set of violations.

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<NotionalProviderPaymentDTO>> violations = validator.validate( notionalProviderPaymentDTO );

        if(!violations.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
        }
```

You can create your own exception mapper which will handle ConstraintViolationException and send the errors messages to the client.

Answer (score 1):

And also:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("mvcValidator")
Validator validator;

...
violations = validator.validate(account);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;

public class{
    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;
       .
       .
    public void validateEmployee(Employee employee){

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Employee>> violations = validator.validate(employee);
        if(!violations.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, 'Employee' is a pojo class and 'employee' is it's object