# Spring MVC: How to manually initiate validation later in controller method

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

I have a controller method that receives a command object containing a list of objects annotated for validation. However, completely empty items should be ignored so I cannot use `@Valid` in controller method header because it would generate an error for all fields of all list items.

I would like to remove the empty lines from the list and call the Spring validator after. How can I do that?

This is a Spring Boot project.

Comment: Please check this post, think there is appropriate example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190592/manually-call-spring-annotation-validation

Comment: I remember finding this earlier I failed to use it. Trying to inject SmartValidator results in No qualifying bean found for dependency [org.springframework.validation.SmartValidator]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. And trying to inject Spring's Validator fails because of finding too many beans, including my custom validators.

Comment: OK, managed to inject by using `@Autowired @Qualifier("mvcValidator")    Validator mvcValidator;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a spring example of how to do validation without the @valid annotation:

```
Foo target = new Foo();
DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(target);
binder.setValidator(new FooValidator());
```

bind to the target object

```
binder.bind(propertyValues);
```

validate the target object

```
binder.validate();
```

get BindingResult that includes any validation errors

```
BindingResult results = binder.getBindingResult();
```

Comment: im sorry but where is propertyValues coming from?

Answer (score 3):

May be its late. But it could come help with others.

Actually you need `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` in your context to explicitly call the validator. In your any context you could decalre the bean like

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
     <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</bean>
```

In your controller `Autowire` the bean and call explicitly for `validate()` method

```
    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @Autowired
    private MyCustomValidator customValidator;

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(smartValidator, customValidator);
    }

    public String save(@ModelAttribute FooModel foo, BindingResult result) {
        // ... your cutom logic and processing
        validator.validate(foo, bindingResult);
        customValidator.validate(foo, bindingResult);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            // ... on any validation errors
        }

        return "view";
    }
```

You could go through [this](https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/tag/localvalidatorfactorybean/) for more about this scenario