# While Doing Request Validation in Springboot, Response is not as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request-validation

I am trying to validate the json-resquest using hibernate-validator, it is working as expected but response is not there in postman.

**Customer.java**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Past;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "cin", "firstName"})
public class Customer {

    @JsonProperty("cin")
    private String cin;

    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    @NotEmpty(message = "First Name must have some values")
    @Size(min = 2, message = "First Name must greater or equal to 2 characters")
    private String firstName;


//getters and setters

}
```

and **Errors class** - to wrap error in one object.

```
public class Errors {

    private Integer status;
    private String message;
    private List<String> details;

    public Errors(Integer status, String message, List<String> details) {
        super();
        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
        this.details = details;
    }
    
// Getters and Setters

}
```

**ControllerAdvice class**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;

import com.ecommerce.ms.customer.model.Errors;

@ControllerAdvice
@ResponseBody
public class CustomerExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value=ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Errors> handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException ex, WebRequest request) {
        List<String> details = ex.getConstraintViolations().parallelStream().map(e -> e.getMessage())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Errors error = new Errors(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), "Request Validation Error", details);
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(error);
    }
}
```

**CustomerController.java**

```
 * 
 */

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ecommerce.ms.customer.api.service.CustomerService;
import com.ecommerce.ms.customer.model.Customer;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/customers")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @GetMapping("/status")
    public String getStatus() {
        return "ok";
    }

    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> addCustomer(@Valid @RequestBody Customer customer) {
        return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(customerService.addCustomer(customer));
    }
}
```

Hibernate-validator is already added pom.xml and I am expecting the below reason.

```
{
   "status":400,
"message": "Request Validation Error",
"details":["First Name must greater or equal to 2 characters"]
}
```

[image: Postman Request]
I am trying to to get proper response body but I couldn't find it in postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler there is no such method that handles ConstraintValidationExceptions, and therefore the custom method you have created is not being called.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html

As well:

> You cannot catch ConstraintViolationException.class because it's not
> propagated to that layer of your code, it's caught by the lower
> layers, wrapped and rethrown under another type. So that the exception
> that hits your web layer is not a ConstraintViolationException.

Ref: [SpringBoot doesn't handle org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45070642/springboot-doesnt-handle-org-hibernate-exception-constraintviolationexception)

An example of proper usage is to use the method handleMethodArgumentNotValid and return the Errors as body:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
                                                                  HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

        Map<String, Object> responseBody = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        List<String> allErrors = new ArrayList<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach(error -> allErrors.add(error.getDefaultMessage()));
        responseBody.put("Errors:", allErrors);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseBody, headers, status);
    }

}
```