# JAX-RS ExceptionMapper not catch javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, jax-rs, javax.validation, exceptionmapper

I have started using javax.validation's `@Valid` annotation to validate data arriving at my REST endpoints. This is working as expected and throwing applicable exceptions:

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [org.<...>.crs.model.RegistrantEntity] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Email address is invalid', propertyPath=email, rootBeanClass=class org.<...>.crs.model.RegistrantEntity, messageTemplate='Email address is invalid'}
```

My understanding of the `ExceptionMapper` is that i should be able to do this:

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class ConstraintViolationExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(exception).build();
    }
}
```

Which should catch that exception and specify an appropriate `Response` object to send back.

This however is not working, here is the full top-level stacktrace items:

```
14:40:46,357 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-1) WFLYEJB0034: Jakarta Enterprise Beans Invocation failed on component AnswerResource for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.<…>.crs.api.AnswerResource.updateAnswer(org.<…>.crs.api.model.Answer,java.util.UUID,java.lang.String) throws java.net.URISyntaxException,java.io.IOException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
…
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
…
    Suppressed: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFTXN0061: Transaction is marked rollback-only
…
    Suppressed: javax.transaction.RollbackException: WFTXN0061: Transaction is marked rollback-only
…
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [org.<…>.crs.model.RegistrantEntity] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Email address is invalid', propertyPath=email, rootBeanClass=class org.<…>.crs.model.RegistrantEntity, messageTemplate='Email address is invalid'}
]
```

My understanding is that the `ConstraintViolationException`, while being the cause, has been packaged in the RollbackException and as such is not caught by ExceptionMapper.

1. Can someone confirm this?
2. If so, is there a way to override this behavior and catch any exception containing a `ConstraintViolationException` inside it?
3. If not, what would be a good work around?

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: Try out the solution here:it should be ok https://stackoverflow.com/a/46344363/7042380

Comment: My issue with this is that i dont want this to catch all RollbackException's, that exception can be thrown for any number of reasons including but not limited to: any exception of any kind thrown in a transaction. This seems to be quite vague and not targeted to the specifics of catching a validation failure.

Comment: ok makes sense. Are you using @Valid in your controller with RequestBody that can be correctly parsed to your entity?? this article should help https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation